# Allow SSH access to a specific user if the IP matches one in a file

Tags: networking, server, ssh, pam, sshd

I need to allow SSH access to my server to `user_a`, from any IP address, and to `user_b`, only if the IP address is in a file - `/etc/remote-hosts`.
Currently, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I have added:

```
AllowUsers user_a user_b
```

This allows both users to connect from any address.
I know I can write something like:

```
AllowUsers user_a user_b@ipaddress1 user_b@ipaddress2
```

This is for an assignment, however, and I was specifically told the IP addresses need to be in the `/etc/remote-hosts` file.

I have a feeling this may be achieved with PAM, but I have looked around and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: I am. Ubuntu server 64-bit.